# Toggle a stored flag on a weekly basis

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a value I would like to switch to another once a week either in the background on when the user launches the app on whichever day even if it's more than a week later. As the user uses the app during the week, each day turns a value e.g. `variable b to false` but every once a week I want to change that variable back to true for any day that it's been turned to false. I have a function I tried putting in the `AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but I am not precisely sure how to do the check and hence it didn't work. This is my attempt:

```
 func resetOnSunday() {

        let date = NSDate()
        let formatter  = NSDateFormatter()
        let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        let WeekDay = formatter.stringFromDate(date)

        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
        let time = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
        if time >= "00:00 AM" && time <= "00:02 AM" && WeekDay == "Sunday" {

 var b = true

        }

    }
```

Does anyone know how it can be done?

Comment: your approach is wrong; you just need to store the last update's date and value, and when the application opens you need to do all the changes directly then, like e.g. mimicking the actual changes would happen in background and the user sees the actual latest and current value only; for example: you need increase a counter by 1 on every Sunday, you store the current value (like e.g. 2) and the current date, and if user will open the app in 5 week time again, you need to count the Sundays since last update and increase the counter by e.g. 5, so the user sees the updated value, 7, immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can significantly cut down your code (and make it a lot more reliable) by using `NSCalendar`.

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
//This will return a NSDate optional which you can check against.
let nextSunday = calendar.nextDateAfterDate(date, matchingUnit: .Weekday, value: 1, options: .MatchNextTime)

if date.timeIntervalSinceDate(nextSunday!) > 0 {
  //Do your stuff here
}
```

Note that:

> Weekday units are the numbers 1 through n, where n is the number of days in the week. For example, in the Gregorian calendar, n is 7 and Sunday is represented by 1.

Next, I would use `NSUserDefaults` for your value:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "yourVar")

//Then to read it
defaults.boolForKey("yourVar")
```